# join matching columns in a data.frame or data.table

Tags: r, merge, dataframe, plyr, data.table

#### I have the following data.frames:

```
a <- data.frame(id = 1:3, v1 = c('a', NA, NA), v2 = c(NA, 'b', 'c'))
b <- data.frame(id = 1:3, v1 = c(NA, 'B', 'C'), v2 = c("A", NA, NA))
> a
  id   v1   v2
1  1    a <NA>
2  2 <NA>    b
3  3 <NA>    c
> b
  id   v1   v2
1  1 <NA>    A
2  2    B <NA>
3  3    C <NA>
```

***note:** There are no ids for which v1 or v2 are defined in both tables; there is only a single unique non-NA value in each column for each id value*

#### I would like to merge these data frames on matching values of "id':

```
ab <- merge(a, b, by = "id")
```

#### but I would also like to combine the two columns `v1` and `v2`, so that the data.frame `ab` will look like this:

```
ab <- data.frame(id = 1:3, v1 = c("a", "B", "C"), v2 = c("A", "b", "c"))

> ab
  id v1 v2
1  1  a  A
2  2  B  b
3  3  C  c
```

#### instead, I get this:

```
> merge(a, b, by = "id")
  id v1.x v2.x v1.y v2.y
1  1    a <NA> <NA>    A
2  2 <NA>    b    B <NA>
3  3 <NA>    c    C <NA>
```

#### it would be helpful to have examples using both `data.frame` and `data.table`, so here are the data.table versions of above:

```
A <- data.table(a, key = 'id')
B <- data.table(b, key = 'id')
A[B]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The type of merge you specify probably won't be possible using `merge` (with data frames), although saying that usually invites being proved wrong.

You also omit some details: will there always be a single unique non-`NA` value in each column for each `id` value? If so, this will work:

```
ab <- rbind(a,b)
> colFun <- function(x){x[which(!is.na(x))]}
> ddply(ab,.(id),function(x){colwise(colFun)(x)})
  id v1 v2
1  1  a  A
2  2  B  b
3  3  C  c
```

A similar strategy should work with `data.table`s as well:

```
abDT <- data.table(ab,key = "id")
> abDT[,list(colFun(v1),colFun(v2)),by = id]
     id V1 V2
[1,]  1  a  A
[2,]  2  B  b
[3,]  3  C  c
```

Comment: The answer is "yes", there will always be "a single unique non-NA value"; this is more clear way to state what I tried to convey in the note under the first code block: "There are no ids for which v1 or v2 are defined in both tables"

Comment: +1 for colwise. I wasn't aware of that funciton, but it looks nifty.

Comment: @TylerRinker I'm not sure I get what you mean by different ids.

Comment: Also, @MatthewDowle would surely be able to suggest a slicker way to apply `colFun` to each column without listing them explicitly.

Comment: Hi. One idiom is `DT[,lapply(.SD,colFun),by=id]`.

Comment: @MatthewDowle I had figured out `lapply(colnames(abDT), colFun)` but was left with unnamed columns; `.SD` is brilliant! and quite fast.

Answer (score 4):

If your data is as simple as it is above joran's answer is likely the simplest way.  Here's may approach in base:

```
a <- data.frame(id = 1:3, v1 = c('a', NA, NA), v2 = c(NA, 'b', 'c'))
b <- data.frame(id = 1:3, v1 = c(NA, 'B', 'C'), v2 = c("A", NA, NA))

decider <- function(x, y) factor(ifelse(is.na(x), as.character(y), as.character(x)))
data.frame(mapply(a, b, FUN = decider))
```

If your data has different id's (some overlap and some do not, then here's a different approach:

```
a <- data.frame(id = c(1,2,4,5), v1 = c('a', NA, "q", NA), v2 = c(NA, 'b', 'c', "e"))
b <- data.frame(id = 1:4, v1 = c(NA, "A", "C", 'B'), v2 = c("A", NA, "D", NA))

decider <- function(x, y) factor(ifelse(is.na(x), as.character(y), as.character(x)))

DF <- data.frame(mapply(a, b, FUN = decider))
DF2 <- rbind(b[!b$id %in% DF$id , ], DF)
DF2 <- DF2[order(DF2$id), ]
rownames(DF2) <- 1:nrow(DF2)
```

Comment: +1 Ah, I see what you mean. Some ids appearing in one df but not the other. I suspect my general strategy would still work in that case, assuming the OP's specification still holds, which would mean that that isolated id wouldn't have any NA values in it.