# R matching two columns in the same data.frame

Tags: r

How can I combind two columns in the same data frame into one column, a simple example would be:

```
a <- data.frame(id = 1:3, v1 = c('a', NA, NA), v2 = c(NA, 'b', 'c'))
a
  id  v1   v2
   1  a   <NA>
   2 <NA>  b
   3 <NA>  c
```

And the output I need would be look like this:

```
a
  id  v1   v2   v3
   1  a   <NA>   a
   2 <NA>  b     b
   3 <NA>  c     c
```

I found a similar post [join matching columns in a data.frame or data.table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9918450/join-matching-columns-in-a-data-frame-or-data-table), but I can not figure it out with my own case, please help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, `ifelse()` maybe?

```
> a <- data.frame(id = 1:3, v1 = c('a', NA, NA), v2 = c(NA, 'b', 'c'),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
> a$v3 <- ifelse(is.na(a$v1), a$v2, a$v1)
> a
  id   v1   v2 v3
1  1    a <NA>  a
2  2 <NA>    b  b
3  3 <NA>    c  c
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear exactly what you want.  What happens if `v1` and `v2` have different values?

This method will prefer the value of `v1`

```
a <- data.frame(id = 1:4, v1 = c('a', NA, NA,'d'), v2 = c(NA, 'b', 'c','e'))

a <- as.data.table(a)
a[,v3 := v1]
a[is.na(v1), v3 := v2]
```

Using traditional `data.frame` methods:

```
a$v3 <- as.character(a$v1)
a[is.na(a$v1),"v3"] <- as.character(a[is.na(a$v1),"v2"])
```