# Merging data frames with not all variables in common

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I'd like to merge two big data frames that don't have all their variables in common. I've tried with 'merge' but I don't get what I want.

An example:

```
# Data frame to merge 1
ID <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
Colour <- c("Red", "Red", "Red", NA, NA)
Flavour <- c("Sweet", "Sweet", "Sweet", NA, NA)
Price <- c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25)
df1 <- data.frame(ID, Colour, Flavour, Price)
rm(ID, Colour, Flavour, Price)

# Data frame to merge 2
ID <- c("4", "5")
Colour <- c("Green", "Green")
Flavour <- c("Bitter", "Bitter")
df2 <- data.frame(ID, Colour, Flavour)
rm(ID, Colour, Flavour)

# What I'd like to get
ID <- c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")
Colour <- c("Red", "Red", "Red", "Green", "Green")
Flavour <- c("Sweet", "Sweet", "Sweet", "Bitter", "Bitter")
Price <- c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25)
RESULT <- data.frame(ID, Colour, Flavour, Price)
rm(ID, Colour, Flavour, Price)
```

Any help greatly appreciated!!

Comment: `df1` and `df2` have _no_ common columns. In such cases you need to explicitly tell `merge` which columns in `df1` relate to which in `df2`, using the `by.x` and `by.x` arguments to `merge`. Have a good read of `?merge`.

Comment: Hi jbaums, thanks for your comment! Sorry, yes, there're common variables. Just edited.

Comment: `merge` doesn't play nicely with that structure (it'll add rows for the NAs). Here's a `plyr` solution: `library(plyr); ab <- rbind.fill(df1, df2); colFun <- function(x){x[which(!is.na(x))]}; ddply(ab, .(ID), function(x){ colwise(colFun)(x) })`. But this is a dupe of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9918450/489704). See also the `data.table` approach given by @joran there.

Comment: thanks for the link! Tried to search for questions on the topic and couldn't find anything.

Comment: Hi, Take a bit of time and read the tag excerpt before tagging. [tag:dataframes] is for pandas, whereas you need [tag:data.frame] here. Be careful the next time. See this meta post. [Warn \[r\] users from adding \[dataframes\] tag instead of \[data.frame\] tag](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318933)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you don't need to merge at all, if what you describe above is exactly what you need. Does this work:

```
# Data frame to merge 1
df1 <- data.frame(ID=c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"),
                  Colour=c("Red", "Red", "Red", NA, NA),
                  Flavour=c("Sweet", "Sweet", "Sweet", NA, NA),
                  Price=c(5, 10, 15, 20, 25),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

df2<- data.frame(ID2=c("4", "5"),
                  Colour2=c("Green", "Green"),
                  Flavour2=c("Bitter", "Bitter"),
                  stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

# Assuming the two dfs are ordered on ID. If not, do so.
df1[df1[["ID"]] %in% df2[["ID2"]],
    c("Colour", "Flavour")] = df2[c("Colour2", "Flavour2")]
```

The idea is to simply replace values from df2 into df1 wherever they are needed.

Answer (score 1):

I would do it as follows:
install `gtools` package

```
library(gtools)
df_new <- smartbind(df1,df2)
```

you will get seven rows, the combination of `df1` and `df2`. to remove unnecessary rows and replace the na's, I use this trick:

```
df_new <- df_new[-1] #remove the ID column

df_new[4:5,][is.na(df_new[4:5,])] <- df_new[6:7,][!is.na(df_new[6:7,])]

df_new <- df_new[complete.cases(df_new),]

df_new$ID <- c(1:nrow(df_new)) #add ID column back
```

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, all=T)` does the same as `smartbind` in this case. (And actually your code throws errors for me - could you double-check it?)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `merge` doesn't play nicely with that structure (it'll add rows for the NAs).

I've retracted my duplicate vote because the question is in fact a bit different.

We can use much of the approach offered by @joran [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9918633/489704), but need to change one small detail. Because your data.frames have different sets of columns, you need to use `rbind.fill` rather than `rbind`.

```
library(plyr)
ab <- rbind.fill(df1, df2)
colFun <- function(x){x[which(!is.na(x))]}
ddply(ab, .(ID), function(x){ colwise(colFun)(x) })

  ID Colour Flavour Price
1  1    Red   Sweet     5
2  2    Red   Sweet    10
3  3    Red   Sweet    15
4  4  Green  Bitter    20
5  5  Green  Bitter    25
```